# ADT 23 doesn't like NDK11

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk

Win7-x64, Eclipse Luna SR2, Android tools v23.0.7. I've installed NDK r11. I'm trying to point Eclipse at `D:\android-ndk-r11` via the Preferences window, but it says:

> "Not a valid NDK directory".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to create an empty file called "ndk-build" (without extension) inside the root folder of the NDK in order to get it recognized by the last version of the ADT plugin.
You can also download my updated version of ADT that supports NDK r11 at: https://github.com/khaledev/ADT.

Comment: @KhaledLakhehal is that any problem occur if i create empty ndk-build file and this also use in android studio?

Comment: @Harin Kaklotar: It should be fine for Android Studio as it is up-to-date with support for the latest NDK version. However, I didn't try it.

Answer (score 7):

I faced this problem too , I fixed it by replace NDK Location with "D:\develop\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\build"  .