# There is no NDK plugin in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android-ndk

I have downloaded and extracted NDK and have set the location in "preferences-->Android-->NDK". Do I have to install NDK plugin from "install new software-->http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"?

The problem is that I have no NDK plugin in this link!

[see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b6Mk.png)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"NDK plugin"_. You [download the NDK separately](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) and install it. Then you [tell Eclipse where you've installed the NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825534/set-build-path-in-eclipse-for-ndk-program). If you get _"Not a valid NDK directory"_ you might've run into [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043047/adt-23-doesnt-like-ndk11).

Comment: Btw, why would you use Juno? That's a 4 year old release.

Comment: did you see the picture? there is no NDK-plugin to install from inside the eclipse. in the picture below the "Delveloper Tools" there should be "NDK-plugin"... but I don't have it. is it because of using old version of eclipse?
http://i.stack.imgur.com/9b6Mk.png

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse ADT Plugin is no longer supported. 
For more info, go to https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/setup-eclipse.html#install