# set the path to NDK directory in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm installing NDK in eclipse I have done this steps :

> nstal Developer Tools (Help -> Instal New Software -> http:////dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/).
>
> Dowload NDK. Extract it.
>
> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> And set NDK path

my problem is when I set the path it says ( not a valid NDK directory )

my system is 64bit and both eclipse and NDK that I downloaded is 64bit
can you help me please to solve it

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043047/adt-23-doesnt-like-ndk11

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Inside the NDK directory, creating a blank file named "ndk-build" (without any extensions) solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Set the path as **C:\android\android-ndk-r12\build**

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of NDK, they have a folder called Build.  Select that folder and the valid NDK Directory check will be validated.